# Dean Professor or Dean and Professor

Tags: nouns

If someone, called John, for example,  has two titles that include Dean and Professor, which of the following expressions is better?

1. Dean Professor John visits Oxford University.
2. Dean and Professor John visits Oxford University.

Comment: In your context which is the more senior ranking? Just use that one!

Comment: Is this just a hypothetical question, or do you know of a title which conveys a prenominal "*Dean*"?

Comment: Use ***one*** or the ***other***. In English, we do not say *"Herr Dekan Professor Doktor Johann*", like they do in German. I would suggest using whichever capacity is related to his visit.

Answer (score 1):

In the British tradition, *Dean* is not used as a title. If you use a title, you also need to use the surname (family name), not the given name (forename).

I would suggest 'Professor Smith, Dean of the Arts Faculty' or similar. In other words, I think 'Dean' needs to be used descriptively rather than as a title.

Answer (score -1):

Can anyone become a dean without being a professor?

if the answer is no; then can we not use Dean John visits Oxford University, as an option here.

this is not an answer; just a suggestion.